# Error: LHR failed to render. (PageSpeed Insights)

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed-insights

When trying to analyze my site with the Google PageSpeed Insights tool, the following error is displayed to me: Error: LHR failed to render, which prevents the page from being analyzed.

I can't find information regarding this problem anywhere. I would like to add that until two days ago no such error appeared and the page was analyzed normally. I'm using Wordpress, haven't installed any new plugins and haven't made any major changes since the last successful attempt to analyze my site in Google PageSpeed Insights.

I cleared the cache on the site, but the effect is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

same. some older threads on this but no real answers But glad I'm not the only one.

Found this on Google boards. Makes sense if you have a picky defense plugin.

"Just check your robots.txt may be you disallow robots function. Or download the lighthouse extension it works the same. "

Answer (score 1):

It's already working at my place. In fact, I waited one day and it was already fine. I'm completely unfamiliar with it, but since I didn't make any changes to the site, didn't even update plugins or theme, it looks like the problem is on the hosting server or google side.